# PRIMEFACES - How to refresh a <p:graphicImage> from clicking a <p:commandButton>?

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces, captcha, page-refresh

I'm considering this showcase: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dynamicImage.jsf in particular the sub-case "GraphicText on-the-fly".

My problem is implementing an extended version of this sub case with the addition of a . When the button is pressed i need that the image change dinamically.

In the DynamicImageController class I re-writed the getter associeted with the graphicImage:

```
public StreamedContent getGraphicText(){
     double random = Math.random();// a double value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0.
     if(random>0.5){
         BufferedImage bufferedImg = new BufferedImage(100, 25, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);  
         Graphics2D g2 = bufferedImg.createGraphics();  
         g2.drawString("This is a text", 0, 10);  
         ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
         try {
            ImageIO.write(bufferedImg, "png", os);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  
         graphicText = new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray()), "image/png");
     } else {
         BufferedImage bufferedImg = new BufferedImage(100, 25, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);  
         Graphics2D g2 = bufferedImg.createGraphics();  
         g2.drawString("This is another text", 0, 10);  
         ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
         try {
            ImageIO.write(bufferedImg, "png", os);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  
         graphicText = new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray()), "image/png");
     }
     return graphicText;
 }
```

I have this button:

```
<p:commandButton id="refreshImageButton" value="Refresh image random">
                <p:ajax update=":idForm" />
             </p:commandButton>
```

and the image:

```
<p:graphicImage value="#{dynamicImageController.graphicText}" />
```

idForm is the form id of the form containing my graphicImage and my commandButton

My question is:

Why if I press the F5 button on the keyboard the image change random consistent with the desired behavior in the getGraphicText method ?
And why when I press the button the image doesn't change?

Thanks.

ps. my real problem is the integration of jcaptcha in primefaces, my integration is almost termineted, i miss only the refresh button for the captcha image

Comment: Who is calling getStream method ?

Comment: I edited, it's not getStream but getGraphicText

Answer (score 12):

By default the `graphicImage` caches the image.
Set the `cache` attribute to `false` on your `p:graphicImage`
Something like this:
`<p:graphicImage value="#{dynamicImageController.graphicText}" cache="false" />`

Comment: @user3147345! you're right about the firefox. i just tested this on firefox and turning cache off doesn't have any effect on it! It appears to be a bug in primefaces implementation. B.t.w which primefaces version are you using?

Comment: Mine is the 4.0 community edition as well! I think we must post this bug to PrimeFaces Bugs list!

Comment: it's working for me, my version is 5.1, not tested on ie, but working on ff and chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Ok update: the problem is a bug of primefaces I discussed here the problems:

http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=35637&p=113830#p113830